# why toast.update in React-Toastify v.9 doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-toastify

why the type and autoClose property does not work? in version 9 of react toastify package.

```
const toast1 = toast.loading("Please wait...");

const data = await setBooks(e);

toast.update(toast1, {
        render: "Oooups.., something goes wrong!",
        type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
        autoClose: 2000,
        closeButton: true,
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the loading to false for the `autoClose` to work.
So add `isLoading: false` to the `toast.update`.

```
toast.update(toast1, {
   render: "Oooups.., something goes wrong!",
   type: toast.TYPE.ERROR,
   autoClose: 2000,
   closeButton: true,
   isLoading: false
});
```